# Rendering entities in queues?

Tags: algorithm, rendering, game-engine

I'm researching game engine architecture and I ran into an implementation where each node in a scenegraph is placed in a particular queue(opaque, transparent, orthographic, etc...) with the queues being rendered in a specific order: opaque, transparent, orthographic. Is there a name for this technique/algorithm for further research?

many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if there is a name for the overall ordering that you mention, but I would assume that the transparent queue is ordered from farthest to nearest, and this is called Alpha Sorting (or [Transparency Sorting](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Transparency_Sorting)).  The opaque objects don't need this, so they can either go first or be sorted along with the transparent obejcts, but not bothering to sort them is obviously faster since you can just let the depth buffer to all the relevant work.